# RSA Archer - Difference between Application and Questionnaire

Tags: archer, rsa-archer-grc

I'm newbie in RSA Archer, I want to know when it's convenient to use a questionnaire instead of an application. I would also like to understand the limits and potential of both objects.
Is it possible to create a cross reference between an application and a questionnaire?
Waiting for your kind help, I thank you in advance.

Comment: Tell us what you have already done: What have read, tried etc.

Answer (score 0):

Giovanni,

An application (just like a questionnaire) you can add fields, rules/actions, advanced workflow, etc.  The difference with a Questionnaire is that it has to target a record within an application.  Meaning you cannot create a questionnaire record without a targeted record, you must first select a record form another application.

Typically you would use a questionnaire to perform an assessment on let say a device, application (non-Archer specific application) or perform a "review" on a policy or control standard.  The questionnaire based on the questions configured would provide "scoring" of that targetted record.  From there a questionnaire can be configured to generate Findings for questions not answered correctly.

There's a plethora of information on the RSA Community (https://community.rsa.com) the can help you along with an active discussion forum.